# Sortable JS , sorting elements from mouse drag/drop

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I hold the mouse and trying drag it to another place, the shadow of the element that follows the mouse is small compared to the element on big screen
[image]

On the small screen (media query < 741px),  it is same size, why?

how mouse "shadow" can same size on full screen too?

[image]

Code is here

```js
var example1 = document.querySelector('#example1');
new Sortable(example1, {
    animation: 150,
    ghostClass: 'blue-background-class'
});
```

```html
<script src="http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">


<h4 class="col-12">Simple list example</h4>
<div id="example1" class="list-group col">
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing, because that doesn't come from the styling you are applying at all to begin with - but this is the default shadow the browser itself draws, when elements get dragged?

Comment: @Cbroe Yes, that's right. How can I add a style specifically for a drop shadow?

Comment: I'd try via one of those classes the items get dynamically added, when you are dragging them.

Comment: When I'm trying to do it on a small screen, this is what I need.

When I do it on the big screen, (after clicking "Run code Spinnet" -> "Full screen", Shadow on big screen is small than element of div, which is clearly visible in the photos

Comment: this happens only on Firefox, I see now.. :(